# Selenium Chrome Driver: How to Load all the Frames and get the Complete Page Source?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#, chromedriver, selenium-webdriver-c#

I'm developing an web application that monitor changes in other websites.
I came across some of the websites and that contain load of Frame set and Frames.

I'm using the below code:

```
  var chromeOption = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOption.AddArgument("--headless");
        Console.WriteLine("Getting into the Application");
        using (var driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOption))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Loading the Web Page");

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.juljensen.dk/");
            var htmltxt = driver.PageSource;
        }
```

The Page Source returns me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
    <title>Mr X. Consulting</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />    
</head>
<frameset cols="25%,50%,25%" frameborder="0">
  <frame src="border.html" />
  <frame src="jjc.html" />
  <frame src="border.html" />
</frameset>
```

The PageSource is not loading the frame source.
I have searched a lot online, even here in vain but didn't get useful info.

My question is how can I load all the frames and get the whole page source like below (only from Inspect element from Chrome)

[image: Page Source from Chrome Inspect Element]

Answer (score 0):

To load all the frames and get the complete page source using Selenium ChromeDriver, you can use the following code:

```
var chromeOption = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOption.AddArgument("--headless");
Console.WriteLine("Getting into the Application");
using (var driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOption))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Loading the Web Page");

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.juljensen.dk/");
    var mainHandle = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
    var handles = driver.WindowHandles;

    foreach (var handle in handles)
    {
        if (handle != mainHandle)
        {
            driver.SwitchTo().Window(handle);
            var htmltxt = driver.PageSource;
            Console.WriteLine(htmltxt);
        }
    }
}
```

This code switches to each frame and gets the page source of each frame. The complete page source can be combined from the page source of each frame.